# Rails: How to get puma 3.11 for AWS Elasticbeanstalk application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Rails app on a new EC2 instance. EB is using puma 2.16.0 (which is 2 years old) instead of the version (3.11.0) I have defined in `Gemfile.lock`. This is a problem for me because the old puma version depends on an older version of `rack` gem. But one of my new dependency requires the latest version of `rack` gem

Current platform of EB: Puma with Ruby 2.3 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.4.4

So EB automatically uses the older puma and older rack version resulting in a conflict with my latest gems:

> /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:317:in check_for_activated_spec!: You have already activated rack 1.6.8, but your Gemfile requires rack 2.0.5. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

I see both versions (the default from EB and the one from Gemfile.lock) installed:

> [ec2-user gems]$ ls -l /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma*
>
> puma-2.16.0
>
> puma-3.11.4

Is there a way to use our own version of puma?

Current platform of EB: Puma with Ruby 2.3 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.4.4

Comment: What command are you running when you see that first error? Have you tried prepending that command with `bundle exec <command>`, like the message suggests?

Comment: EB manages(/abstracts) the deployment and application restart commands. So I think apps should not overwrite or extend how to manager their app instances.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a pretty old version of the ElasticBeanstalk Puma platform - the latest version is `Puma with Ruby 2.5 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.2`. Unfortunately, that still comes with Puma 2.16. Installing two different versions of Puma simultaneously will probably cause issues.

I think you have a few options:

1. Switch from puma to passenger.
2. Downgrade the other gem that depends on rack to a version that can work with the older version of rack
3. Ask AWS support to upgrade Puma in the platform.

Comment: Yes, I checked the latest EB version too, only to realize that is running the same puma version.